Plot cutaway of dense area in map using matplotlib
I'm trying to plot a national vote share map using Matplotlib, which I was successful at doing, and now I'm trying to take it to the next level and include a cutaway of the capital region to make it easier to read. In this example, a_2020 is a dataframe that has the vote share + shapefiles for a party by constituency nationwide, while a_dublin has that same data but just for the constituencies in Dublin. Here is the code I'm using to plot it:
a_combined_path = 'c:\\my_path'
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
fig.set_size_inches(10,10)
a_2020.plot(ax=ax1, column='Party Vote Share', cmap='Greens', edgecolor='black', linewidth = 0.5)
a_dublin.plot(ax=ax2, column='Party Vote Share', cmap='Greens', legend=True, edgecolor='black', linewidth = 0.5)
ax1.set_axis_off()
ax2.set_axis_off()
fig.suptitle('Aontú vote share in the 2020 elections\nby constituency (Pct of total vote)', size = 16)
plt.savefig(a_combined_path, dpi=600)

The result is below. While I plan on tinkering around with the aesthetics (e.g., element positions), my main issue at the minute is that the Dublin cutaway does not show quite what I want; the cutaway shows data relative to just Dublin, not to the entire country.
Does anyone know of a better approach?


Add the same norm parameter to both plot commands, i.e.
import matplotlib as mpl

[...]

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(
    vmin=a_2020["Party Vote Share"].min(), 
    vmax=a_2020["Party Vote Share"].max()
)
a_2020.plot(ax=ax1, column='Party Vote Share', cmap='Greens', norm=norm, ...)
a_dublin.plot(ax=ax2, column='Party Vote Share', cmap='Greens', norm=norm, ...)

[...]

You can read more about colormap normalization here.

You were dead on! Cheers mate, there's no way I would have found that parameter on my own.
